# Linux | grep date informat "Aug 14"

Tags: linux, bash, date, scripting, grep

I am writing a script where I need to do `ls -l` and `grep` files of today's date in "Aug 14" format. I assigned the date in a variable as `dt=date "+%b %d"` but I am not able to get the files.

In what way I can achieve that?

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#1st Argument i.e., $1 will be file name and 2nd Argument i.e., $2 will be directory path where file is located.

cd $2

command=`ls -l | grep $dt| grep $1`

if 

    [ -z "$command" ]; then

    echo "Critical : File $1 doesn't exists for $dt"
    exit 2


else

    echo "OK : File $1 exists for $dt"
    exit 0

fi
```

Running the script:

Comment: Wrap the grep in quotes and turn it into a command: ` ls -l | grep "$(date "+%b %d")" `

Comment: Can you please make your question clearer? Are you trying to find files with the date in the file name or in the file contents?

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: @kaylum I am trying to check if a particular with today's timespan exists. Bob's answer worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I have the impression you need to do something, you have chosen a way to do it and you have problems implementing that way, leading you to this question.

You need to "list the files of today in the current directory".
As a way to do this, you have checked `ls -l` output and you want to render this, therefore you have formatted today's date as "Aug 14".
You seem to have problems with that rendering.

As mentioned by Cyrus, it's not a good idea to render `ls` results, so the way you have chosen is not good.

What's a better solution?

You might work with `find`, but as you are only interested in current directory, you need to limit the depth of the search (which you can achieve using `-maxdepth`), so I propose you following command (the `-mtime -1` gives you the files, which have been modified at most one day ago):

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -mtime -1
```

Is this what you are looking for?

**Edit:**

A small extra as requested by Kvantour: you might use the `mtime` switch multiple times for searching for a date range, like the list of files, being changed at least one week, but less than two weeks ago, as follows:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -mtime -14 -mtime +7
```

Comment: This answer would be great if you could generalise this to a date-range.

Comment: @kvantour: I've adapted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

quoting the variable as below worked for me.

dt="date '+%b %d'"